# Converting string to date 2021-12-10T00:00:00 in java

Tags: java, string, date

I'm tring to convert this date string "2021-12-10T00:00:00" into a Date but when i deserialize it i got this.

Thu Dec 09 19:00:00 COT 2021.
it seems I'm losing one day.

Can anyone help me?

`"startDate": "2021-12-10T00:00:00",` and the result is this
`2021-12-09T19:00:00.000-0500`

Comment: It's more likely just a display issue based on your current locale

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("2021-12-10T00:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);` seems to produce an acceptable result for me

Comment: Do you know the time zone or offset from UTC intended for the date and time contained in your input?

Comment: No, without seeing your code I am afraid that no one can help you, Also if by *Date* you meant `java.util.Date`, don’t use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated, Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
java.util.Date.from(
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( "2021-12-10T00:00:00" ) 
    .atZone( 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Bogota" )
    )
    .toInstant()
)
```

## Details

I am guessing that you are using the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`. Don’t. Use only *java.time* class.

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard for date-time formats. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-12-10T00:00:00" ) ;
```

You said:

> I'm tring to convert this date string "2021-12-10T00:00:00" into a Date

That does not make sense.

I assume by “Date”, you meant a `java.until.Date`. That legacy class represents a moment, a point on the timeline as seen in UTC, that is, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

But your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset. For example, if that string was meant to represent a moment as seen in UTC, it should have had a `Z` appended.

I am guessing that you assume the input was meant to represent a moment as seen in Colombia.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Bogota" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now we have determined a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of Colombia.

Generally best to avoid `java.util.Date` class. But if you must, to interoperate with legacy code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your start date is `2021-12-10 00:00:00 GMT+0` and your result is `2021-12-09 19:00:00  GMT-5`. These times are the same. You can pass a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to your [SimpleDataFormat constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) to be able to configure the used time zone.

Comment: I very much hope that the OP is not using `SimpleDateFormat`, That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Also `Locale` is not relevant. Time zone and/or offset from UTC is.